# how we can return a value of select to each property of entities?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm new to entity faramwork. I'm trying to find best code for returning my select value to my entity property 
here is my code:

```
private void CustomerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CustomerID != null && CustomerMode !=(int)CustomerModeOperaton.insert)
        {
            using (var Context = new FactorEntities())
            {
                    var Customercods =  from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerCode;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerCode = Customercods.First();
                    var Customernames = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerName;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerName = Customernames.First();
                    var Customerlastname = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerLastName;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerLastName = Customerlastname.First();
                    var customerID = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerID;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerID = customerID.First();
                    var customerAddresses = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerAdresse;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerAdresse = customerAddresses.First();
                    var customerMobile = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerCellPhone;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerCellPhone = customerMobile.First();
                    var customerphone = from _customers in Context.tblCustomers.Where(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID) select _customers.CustomerPhone;
                    _tblCustomer.CustomerPhone = customerphone.First();

            }

        }

        LoadDataToControl();
}
```

but I was wondering if I use this code, I have to use several select which is not good and what should I do if my select value be null?
for example this code:

```
_tblCustomer.CustomerPhone = customerphone.First();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to query for the customer once, and let it return all the customer's information in one object. Then you can just reference the properties of that object for your assignments to the `_tblCustomer` fields.

If you use `FirstOrDefault`, then you can just check that the returned object is not `null` before trying to use it (in the case where there is no customer whose `CustomerID` matches the one your searching for):

```
var customer = Context.tblCustomers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CustomerID == CustomerID);

if (customer != null)
{
    _tblCustomer.CustomerCode = customer.CustomerCode; 
    _tblCustomer.CustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerLastName = customer.CustomerLastName;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerID = customer.CustomerID;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerAdresse = customer.CustomerAdresse;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerCellPhone = customer.CustomerCellPhone;
    _tblCustomer.CustomerPhone = customer.CustomerPhone;
}
```